# Cant draw on UIImage inside a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I have a custom UIView , inside which I have to show an image as a background and draw freely on to it using touches and drags, referred to this question iOS: [iOS: Drawing line is appearing behind subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167757/ios-drawing-line-is-appearing-behind-subviews),
but doesn't seems to be working,it draws image but doesn't draw anything over it , please help

Following custom UiView draws free hand

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder // (1)
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO]; // (2)
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    }


    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect // (5)
{

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}


@end
```

This is the main UIView inside I have added UiImage and OverlayView

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder // (1)
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        CGRect rect1 = self.frame;
        rect1.origin.x = 0;
        rect1.origin.y = 0;

        UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect1.origin.x,rect1.origin.y,rect1.size.width,rect1.size.height)];
        dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"miter"];
        [self addSubview:dot];

        OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect1.origin.x,rect1.origin.y,rect1.size.width,rect1.size.height)];
        [overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [self addSubview:overlay];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:overlay];

    }


    return self;
}



@end
```

Comment: You haven't described how it doesn't work, do you get a line, where is it, etc...

Comment: @wain it doesn't draw any line when i swipe finger on screen, image appears at the background but nothing gets drawn over it

Comment: Are your touches methods being called?

Comment: @wain , no they aren't

Comment: so that is very important information, you need to work out why, and we can't tell from the details in the question

Answer (score 0):

Set the userInteractionEnabled property to YES. The default for UIViews is YES, but for UIImageViews is NO so you have to explicitly turn it on.